# Empty Radiator with no leaks

Tags: ford, radiator, ranger

I have a 1998 Ford Ranger 4 cycl. and 8 spark plugs which all the water was gone in the radiator with no leaks to be found...What would cause water to totally evaporate from radiator without any leaks and cause smoke from rear and truck to totally stop.    Ps  this is also a stick shift...

Comment: And today I learned that Ford made an engine with 2 spark plugs per cylinder...

Comment: So, white smoke was coming out of the truck, but then stopped when the radiator went dry?  The water had to go somewhere...

Answer (score 3):

This is probably very bad news.  It sounds like all your coolant has been sucked through the engine and blown out of the exhaust.  Once all the coolant had gone, the engine will have over heated and siezed. The only thing I can think of that would have caused this is a blown cylinder head gasket.  The engine may need a lot of work, or need replacing, unless someone can give some better news.